# Hookrightarrow equivalent in XYMatrix

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

I would like to have a `\hookrightarrow`-like arrow in an `\xymatrix` environment. I am aware that the suggested code for this is `\ar@{^{(}->}[r]`, but I find the arc at the arrow's source to be unproportionally large and not quite what I am looking for. This example illustrates the problem quite well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}  
\UseAllTwocells
\SelectTips{eu}{10}

\begin{document}
\[ \xymatrix{ A \ar@{^{(}->}[r] & B } \]
\[ A \hookrightarrow B \]
\end{document}
```

I have tried to create something with `\newdir` that resembles the `\hookrightarrow` more, but frankly I do not seem to properly comprehend the way this works.

It is important for me that the arrow tip works for arrows with any angle of orientation, not just left to right ones. Whatever I created with `\newdir` would result in a misplaced arc for some orientation of the arrow, and eventually I gave up to ask for help here.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide an arrow tip that satisfies all these requirements, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A very big defect of Xy-pic.

Comment: Any updates here? Does the problem still exists?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Unfortunately, I never got it to really look the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not bound to `\xymatrix`, with `tikz-cd` it is very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[r, hook] & B\ar[d, hook]\\
C\ar[u, hook] & D\ar[l, hook] 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[ A \hookrightarrow B \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the necromancy! I am long past this problem, but I appreciate the solution anyway =).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I was looking through the old questions searching for something to answer :) Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 2):

My proposal using the `xy` package as requested by the user. I hope it'll help. Obviously you can change the lengths of the rows (`R`) or columns (`C`) with the string `@R=4em@C=4em`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

\xymatrix@R=4em@C=4em{\ar@{^{(}->}[r] 
A \, \ar[r] & \,B \ar@{^{(}->}[d] \\
B\,  \ar@{^{(}->}[u]& \ar@{^{(}->}[l] \,C}
\end{document}
```